# Elasticsearch too many open files

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Problem: I've got 5 Nodes (1xMaster,1xClient,3xData)! They all run in the same Cluster. After uploading a huge number of Data sets I've got the following Exceptions:

```
[2016-04-18 09:00:24,907][INFO ][node                     ] [Human Torch II] version[2.2.0], pid[68278], build[8ff36d1/2016-01-27T13:32:39Z]
[2016-04-18 09:00:24,908][INFO ][node                     ] [Human Torch II] initializing ...
[2016-04-18 09:00:25,483][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Human Torch II] modules [lang-expression, lang-groovy], plugins [], sites []
[2016-04-18 09:00:25,530][INFO ][env                      ] [Human Torch II] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/disk1)]], net usable_space [352.6gb], net total_space [464.8gb], spins? [unknown], types [hfs]
[2016-04-18 09:00:25,530][INFO ][env                      ] [Human Torch II] heap size [1.9gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2016-04-18 09:00:28,200][INFO ][node                     ] [Human Torch II] initialized
[2016-04-18 09:00:28,200][INFO ][node                     ] [Human Torch II] starting ...
[2016-04-18 09:00:28,322][INFO ][transport                ] [Human Torch II] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {[fe80::1]:9300}, {[::1]:9300}, {127.0.0.1:9300}
[2016-04-18 09:00:28,329][INFO ][discovery                ] [Human Torch II] TEST/xSxhxmpYQ9SPk4Ux8SufpQ
[2016-04-18 09:00:31,357][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Human Torch II] new_master {Human Torch II}{xSxhxmpYQ9SPk4Ux8SufpQ}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{master=true}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
[2016-04-18 09:00:31,371][INFO ][http                     ] [Human Torch II] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {[fe80::1]:9200}, {[::1]:9200}, {127.0.0.1:9200}
[2016-04-18 09:00:31,371][INFO ][node                     ] [Human Torch II] started
[2016-04-18 09:00:31,740][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Human Torch II] recovered [128] indices into cluster_state
[2016-04-18 09:00:50,810][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Human Torch II] added {{Xi'an Chi Xan}{OQjiTz-sR0Wcg8yIYnbSBA}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9301}{data=false, master=false},}, reason: zen-disco-join(join from node[{Xi'an Chi Xan}{OQjiTz-sR0Wcg8yIYnbSBA}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9301}{data=false, master=false}])
[2016-04-18 09:00:56,049][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Human Torch II] added {{Riot}{VZQyBWSxS_W3H33_Xpx7kw}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9302}{master=false},}, reason: zen-disco-join(join from node[{Riot}{VZQyBWSxS_W3H33_Xpx7kw}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9302}{master=false}])
[2016-04-18 09:01:01,727][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Human Torch II] added {{Topaz}{SShnnKN7SHKaxBGmn3TCig}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9303}{master=false},}, reason: zen-disco-join(join from node[{Topaz}{SShnnKN7SHKaxBGmn3TCig}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9303}{master=false}])
[2016-04-18 09:01:15,400][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Human Torch II] added {{Moondark}{j9oCYfm_TbW0cdEciwyBhQ}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9304}{master=false},}, reason: zen-disco-join(join from node[{Moondark}{j9oCYfm_TbW0cdEciwyBhQ}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9304}{master=false}])
[2016-04-18 09:01:30,174][WARN ][cluster.action.shard     ] [Human Torch II] [logstash-2015.09.26][0] received shard failed for [logstash-2015.09.26][0], node[j9oCYfm_TbW0cdEciwyBhQ], [P], v[17], s[INITIALIZING], a[id=p6bW6TXYS9yJGiWpUbDkrg], unassigned_info[[reason=CLUSTER_RECOVERED], at[2016-04-18T07:00:31.474Z]], indexUUID [xgsq0ZPVQ5OIdadydVB9rA], message [failed recovery], failure [IndexShardRecoveryException[failed to recovery from gateway]; nested: EngineCreationFailureException[failed to open reader on writer]; nested: NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[/Users/Desktop/elasticsearch-2.2.0Data3/data/TEST/nodes/0/indices/logstash-2015.09.26/0/index/_0.si: Too many open files in system]; ]
[logstash-2015.09.26][[logstash-2015.09.26][0]] IndexShardRecoveryException[failed to recovery from gateway]; nested: EngineCreationFailureException[failed to open reader on writer]; nested: NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[/Users/Desktop/elasticsearch-2.2.0Data3/data/TEST/nodes/0/indices/logstash-2015.09.26/0/index/_0.si: Too many open files in system];
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.StoreRecoveryService.recoverFromStore(StoreRecoveryService.java:254)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.StoreRecoveryService.access$100(StoreRecoveryService.java:56)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.StoreRecoveryService$1.run(StoreRecoveryService.java:129)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: [logstash-2015.09.26][[logstash-2015.09.26][0]] EngineCreationFailureException[failed to open reader on writer]; nested: NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[/Users/Desktop/elasticsearch-2.2.0Data3/data/TEST/nodes/0/indices/logstash-2015.09.26/0/index/_0.si: Too many open files in system];
    at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine.createSearcherManager(InternalEngine.java:308)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine.<init>(InternalEngine.java:167)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngineFactory.newReadWriteEngine(InternalEngineFactory.java:25)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.newEngine(IndexShard.java:1450)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.createNewEngine(IndexShard.java:1434)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.internalPerformTranslogRecovery(IndexShard.java:925)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.performTranslogRecovery(IndexShard.java:897)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.StoreRecoveryService.recoverFromStore(StoreRecoveryService.java:245)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[/Users/Desktop/elasticsearch-2.2.0Data3/data/TEST/nodes/0/indices/logstash-2015.09.26/0/index/_0.si: Too many open files in system]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:177)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:287)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:335)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NIOFSDirectory.openInput(NIOFSDirectory.java:82)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FileSwitchDirectory.openInput(FileSwitchDirectory.java:186)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FilterDirectory.openInput(FilterDirectory.java:89)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FilterDirectory.openInput(FilterDirectory.java:89)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.Directory.openChecksumInput(Directory.java:109)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene50.Lucene50SegmentInfoFormat.read(Lucene50SegmentInfoFormat.java:82)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.readCommit(SegmentInfos.java:362)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$1.doBody(SegmentInfos.java:493)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$1.doBody(SegmentInfos.java:490)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:731)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:683)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.readLatestCommit(SegmentInfos.java:490)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.Lucene.readSegmentInfos(Lucene.java:95)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.store.Store.readSegmentsInfo(Store.java:163)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.store.Store.readLastCommittedSegmentsInfo(Store.java:148)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.Engine.readLastCommittedSegmentInfos(Engine.java:349)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine.createSearcherManager(InternalEngine.java:298)
    ... 12 more
    Suppressed: NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[/Users/Desktop/elasticsearch-2.2.0Data3/data/TEST/nodes/0/indices/logstash-2015.09.26/0/index/_0.si: Too many open files in system]
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:177)
        at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:287)
        at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:335)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.NIOFSDirectory.openInput(NIOFSDirectory.java:82)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.FileSwitchDirectory.openInput(FileSwitchDirectory.java:186)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.FilterDirectory.openInput(FilterDirectory.java:89)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.FilterDirectory.openInput(FilterDirectory.java:89)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.Directory.openChecksumInput(Directory.java:109)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene50.Lucene50SegmentInfoFormat.read(Lucene50SegmentInfoFormat.java:82)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.readCommit(SegmentInfos.java:362)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.Lucene.readSegmentInfos(Lucene.java:128)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.Engine.readLastCommittedSegmentInfos(Engine.java:345)
        ... 13 more
```

I can't start elasticsearch anymore. 
so questions:

1. Is there a upload data size limit?
2. I've tried to increase the number of max open files with sudo ulimit -n 65535 but it doesn't work. Is this the actual problem?
3. What ist the best way to handle very Big Data?
4. Could the heap size be a reason for the exceptions?

Update: curl -s -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?v&h=ip,fdc,fdm'

```
ip         fdc  fdm 
127.0.0.1 2588 9000 
127.0.0.1 1942 9000 
127.0.0.1 1896 9000 
127.0.0.1 2823 9000 
127.0.0.1  338 9000
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Can you update your question with the output you get from `curl -s -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?v&h=ip,fdc,fdm'` This will output the effective number of max open files you can have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so you have 5 nodes on the same host and you can have maximum 9000 open files. If you sum up the second column you're above that number, hence the error you're getting.

In order to see during startup how many max open files your ES is configured with, you can start your process with `-Des.max-open-files=true` and your log will show you how many max open files you can have.

Check [here](http://pro.benjaminste.in/post/318453669/increase-the-number-of-file-descriptors-on-centos) and [here](http://posidev.com/blog/2009/06/04/set-ulimit-parameters-on-ubuntu/) (depends on what Linux distro you have) on how to configure that settings for your Linux distro, but you might have to tweak `/etc/security/limits.conf` as well.

Comment: Thank you very much :) you are the hero of the day :)